# PyRoute2 :: Psutil equivalent?

Tags: linux, multithreading, python-3.x, networking, namespaces

I am aware this is a perfect candidate for waving me some RTFMs, however I could not find the answer in the Pyroute2 doc.

I started playing aroung with this module and enjoy very much the support for network namespaces, however, in order to collect 'ifconfig-like' information related to a NIC (inside a netns or not), I can't get the appropriate method.

I am looking for: link status (of the NIC *AND* of the....link, yes Linux), the Rx/Tx bytes/pckts/errors counters, speed/duplex,etc...

I manage to get the MAC, ip, MTU,...and much more from `.dump()` but not the rest. Typically something you can pull out of [psutil.net_if_stats()](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.net_if_stats) and/or [psutil.net_io_counters()](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.net_io_counters) 
However, psutil works fine for root namespace, but not for other netns (even using 'with' context will break the net_if_stats() one... :/ )

I wish I could do everything from Pyroute2 and drop psutil...

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

As Svinota himself responded:

> You may retrieve all the possible stats via IPRoute:

```
> from pprint import pprint from pyroute2 import IPRoute
> 
> with IPRoute() as ipr:
>     pprint(ipr.get_links())
```

> In the case of the namespaces you can use NetNS as a drop-in for
>   IPRoute, just change all the IPRoute in the code to NetNS:

```
> from pyroute2 import NetNS
> 
> with NetNS('test') as ns:
>     ns.get_links()
```